# Unknown provider: RequestsServiceProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app.js I do like this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, RequestsService) {

});
```

and it my service.js

```
angular.module('starter')
    .service('RequestsService', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading',  function(){
    //something
}]);
```

But why am I getting error of Unknown provider: RequestsServiceProvider? It's ionic but this is angularjs related error.

Comment: is your `service.js` file included in the `index.html` file?

Comment: @KhaledShaaban yes. solved, it was misspelled of my folder name, ouch!

Comment: EDIT: Happens to us all :D